# Gradle build failed for unity project when building for android

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, gradle, groovy

I am getting the following error when i build my unity project for Android:

Gradle build failed. See the console for details.

Here is the full stack trace:

startup failed:
  General error during class generation: 1913

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1913    at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.CallSiteWriter.getCreateArraySignature(CallSiteWriter.java:58)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.CallSiteWriter.makeCallSite(CallSiteWriter.java:317)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.makeCachedCall(InvocationWriter.java:307)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.makeCall(InvocationWriter.java:397)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.makeCall(InvocationWriter.java:104)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.makeInvokeMethodCall(InvocationWriter.java:88)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.writeInvokeMethod(InvocationWriter.java:464)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitMethodCallExpression(AsmClassGenerator.java:771)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.MethodCallExpression.visit(MethodCallExpression.java:66)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.StatementWriter.writeReturn(StatementWriter.java:590)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OptimizingStatementWriter.writeReturn(OptimizingStatementWriter.java:324)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitReturnStatement(AsmClassGenerator.java:620)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.ReturnStatement.visit(ReturnStatement.java:49)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.StatementWriter.writeBlockStatement(StatementWriter.java:85)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OptimizingStatementWriter.writeBlockStatement(OptimizingStatementWriter.java:159)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitBlockStatement(AsmClassGenerator.java:570)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.BlockStatement.visit(BlockStatement.java:71)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitClassCodeContainer(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:104)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitConstructorOrMethod(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:115)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitStdMethod(AsmClassGenerator.java:434)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitConstructorOrMethod(AsmClassGenerator.java:387)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitMethod(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:126)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitMethod(AsmClassGenerator.java:511)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.visitContents(ClassNode.java:1081)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitClass(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:53)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitClass(AsmClassGenerator.java:233)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$17.call(CompilationUnit.java:825)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$17.call(CompilationUnit.java:842)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$17.call(CompilationUnit.java:842)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1065)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:603)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:581)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:558)
>     at
>   groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
>     at
>   groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
>     at
>   org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptCompilationHandler.compileScript(DefaultScriptCompilationHandler.java:135)
>     at
>   org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptCompilationHandler.compileToDir(DefaultScriptCompilationHandler.java:95)
>     at
>   org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler$CompileToCrossBuildCacheAction.execute(FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler.java:154)
>     at
>   org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler$CompileToCrossBuildCacheAction.execute(FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler.java:135)
>     at
>   org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler$ProgressReportingInitializer.execute(FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler.java:178)
>     at
>   org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler$ProgressReportingInitializer.execute(FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler.java:158)
>     at
>   org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryCache$Initializer.initialize(DefaultPersistentDirectoryCache.java:103)
>     at
>   org.gradle.cache.internal.FixedSharedModeCrossProcessCacheAccess$1.run(FixedSharedModeCrossProcessCacheAccess.java:73)
>     at
>   org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.doWriteAction(DefaultFileLockManager.java:184)
>     at
>   org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.writeFile(DefaultFileLockManager.java:174)
>     at
>   org.gradle.cache.internal.FixedSharedModeCrossProcessCacheAccess.open(FixedSharedModeCrossProcessCacheAccess.java:71)
>     at
>   org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.open(DefaultCacheAccess.java:133)
>     at
>   org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.open(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:57)
>     at
>   org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.open(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:30)
>     at
>   org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory.doOpen(DefaultCacheFactory.java:89)
>     at
>   org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory.open(DefaultCacheFactory.java:63)
>     at
>   org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheRepository$PersistentCacheBuilder.open(DefaultCacheRepository.java:123)
>     at
>   org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler$RemapBuildScriptsAction.execute(FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler.java:400)
>     at
>   org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler$RemapBuildScriptsAction.execute(FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler.java:376)
>     at
>   org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler$ProgressReportingInitializer.execute(FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler.java:178)
>     at
>   org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler$ProgressReportingInitializer.execute(FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler.java:158)
>     at
>   org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryCache$Initializer.initialize(DefaultPersistentDirectoryCache.java:103)
>     at
>   org.gradle.cache.internal.FixedSharedModeCrossProcessCacheAccess$1.run(FixedSharedModeCrossProcessCacheAccess.java:73)
>     at
>   org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.doWriteAction(DefaultFileLockManager.java:184)
>     at
>   org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.writeFile(DefaultFileLockManager.java:174)
>     at
>   org.gradle.cache.internal.FixedSharedModeCrossProcessCacheAccess.open(FixedSharedModeCrossProcessCacheAccess.java:71)
>     at
>   org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.open(DefaultCacheAccess.java:133)
>     at
>   org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.open(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:57)
>     at
>   org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.open(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:30)
>     at
>   org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory.doOpen(DefaultCacheFactory.java:89)
>     at
>   org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory.open(DefaultCacheFactory.java:63)
>     at
>   org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheRepository$PersistentCacheBuilder.open(DefaultCacheRepository.java:123)
>     at
>   org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler.compile(FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler.java:104)
>     at
>   org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.CrossBuildInMemoryCachingScriptClassCache.getOrCompile(CrossBuildInMemoryCachingScriptClassCache.java:52)
>     at
>   org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.BuildScopeInMemoryCachingScriptClassCompiler.compile(BuildScopeInMemoryCachingScriptClassCompiler.java:48)
>     at
>   org.gradle.groovy.scripts.DefaultScriptCompilerFactory$ScriptCompilerImpl.compile(DefaultScriptCompilerFactory.java:50)
>     at
>   org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:177)
>     at
>   org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.run(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:61)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:317)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:309)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:185)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:95)
>     at
>   org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.apply(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:58)
>     at
>   org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:39)
>     at
>   org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
>     at
>   org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
>     at
>   org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.doConfigure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:63)
>     at
>   org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.access$100(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:33)
>     at
>   org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$ConfigureProject.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:103)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:317)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:309)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:185)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:95)
>     at
>   org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:49)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:654)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:132)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:35)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:60)
>     at
>   org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:38)
>     at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$ConfigureBuild.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:195)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:317)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:309)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:185)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:95)
>     at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:157)
>     at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:44)
>     at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:122)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService$2.execute(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:124)
>     at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:116)
>     at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:99)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:66)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:317)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:309)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:185)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:95)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:51)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:51)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:64)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:29)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:55)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:42)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:50)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:30)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you find a solution? I too am now having this issue and I cannot find which plugin is causing it.

Answer (score 2):

For me, this was an issue with the `aaptOptions` section (specifically `noCompress`) of the build.gradle file exported. Apparently there's a limit to how long that section can be. I was able to resolve it by consolidating files listed individually (Wwise's `.wem` and `.bnk`) into plain extensions to reduce the count.

So

```
aaptOptions {
    noCompress '.unity3d', '.ress', '.resource', '.obb', 'desc.txt', 'audio/generatedsoundbanks/wwise_ids.h', 'audio/generatedsoundbanks/android/100296979.wem', 'audio/generatedsoundbanks/android/1002970682.wem', 'audio/generatedsoundbanks/android/1008352514.wem', 'audio/generatedsoundbanks/android/1020575901.wem', 'audio/generatedsoundbanks/android/1029505146.wem', 'audio/generatedsoundbanks/android/1032519289.wem', 'audio/generatedsoundbanks/android/1037720794.wem', 'audio/generatedsoundbanks/android/1046327601.wem', 'audio/generatedsoundbanks/android/110587467.wem', 'audio/generatedsoundbanks/android/156370390.wem',
```

became

```
aaptOptions {
    noCompress '.unity3d', '.ress', '.resource', '.obb', 'desc.txt', 'audio/generatedsoundbanks/wwise_ids.h', '.wem',
```

for example.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps someone, 
Try By following. When i used it error is go away.

> `Split Application Binary" (APK + OBB)`

Comment: In case anyone is looking for additional steps for splliting the app binary: https://docs.unity3d.com/530/Documentation/Manual/android-OBBsupport.html

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was essentially the same as what DWishR mentioned, with too many files listed in the `noCompress` section of the build.gradle file. In my case, each resource was listed individually, and that came to over 300 fields in the `noCompress` option. Removing some of the fields allowed it to build, but I removed all of "bin/data/*.resource" entries, as it seemed not to hurt the APK size.